# Drag Drop with multiselect

Tags: winforms, drag-and-drop, multi-select

I've implemented drag-and-drop from a listbox to a treeview with the help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495666/c-drag-drop-from-listbox-to-treeview).  The only thing I haven't figured out yet is how to drag more than one item from the listbox.  I've enabled multiselect on the listbox, but when I have multiple items selected and start the drag, it deselects everything except for the item directly under the mouse pointer.  Has anyone gotten drag-and-drop to work with multiselect, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep the ctrl or shift key pressed when you begin the drop, if you let go the listbox goes back to 'begin select' mode again.

Answer (score 0):

I see this as a bug in the framework as the multi-select behaviour is different to the one in Windows Explorer and is not intuitive at all. See my suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553622/wpf-drag-drop-from-listbox-with-selectionmode-multiple/20113057#20113057).