# how to Drag&Drop in the same ListView?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, drag-and-drop

I have a small file explorer application [WINFORMS], and i use ListView Control to explore items.
So the listView display the files and the folders from the current address [From local Computer].
i need to enable drag&drop functionality to let a File/Folder easy to move/copy to another Folder in the same Address.
each item has some preperties:

**(item.Text/item.Name)**  has the file/folder **Name**.

**item.ToolTipText**  has the file/folder **Path**.

**item.SubItems[ 1 ].Text** for a file it will respresent the file size like `"13.45 MB"` and for a folder, it's going to be `string.Empty` *[However, there's several way to know whether its a file or a folder].*

I've seen many tutorials about how to use drag&drop in listview, but it was like from Windows File Explorer to ListView, or from a ListView to another one, but in my case i need to know how to **drag&drop in the same ListView**.

I've Enabled AllowDrop property of the ListView. and also Activated the following functions:

```
    private void listView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void listView1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void listView1_ItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

[image]

## UPDATE:

i tried to use this :

```
private void listView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)e.Data.GetData(typeof(ListViewItem)); //this should be the target item (FOLDER)
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (ListViewItem i in listView1.SelectedItems)
        {
            s.AppendLine(i.Text);
        }
        MessageBox.Show("DRAGGED ITEM : " + s.ToString() + "TARGET ITEM : " + item.Text);
    }
    private void listView1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }
    private void listView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = listView1.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y);
        if (item != null)
        {
            listView1.DoDragDrop(item, DragDropEffects.Copy);
        }
    }
```

at `listView1_MouseDown` i get the item which mouse points onto, but it gives me the item before i drop the dragged item, so if i am dragging a folder named "SWImg" to the folder "ODDFiles" , the messageBox shows `"SWImg - SWImg"`

then i replaced `listView1_MouseDown` with `listView1_ItemDrag` :

```
private void listView1_ItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item != null)
        {
            listView1.DoDragDrop(e.Item, DragDropEffects.Copy);
        }
    }
```

same result :S.

Comment: read this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495666/c-sharp-drag-drop-from-listbox-to-treeview

Comment: @Likurg that doesn't work for me.

Comment: I'll try to do example for you, but i'll do it tomorrow, ok?

Comment: @Likurg i've updated my question, i tried something from your link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out.

```
private void listView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 0) { return; }
        Point p = listView1.PointToClient(MousePosition);
        ListViewItem item = listView1.GetItemAt(p.X, p.Y);
        if (item == null) { return; }
        List<ListViewItem> collection = new List<ListViewItem>();
        foreach (ListViewItem i in listView1.SelectedItems)
        {
            collection.Add((ListViewItem)i.Clone());
        }
        if ((e.Effect & DragDropEffects.Move) == DragDropEffects.Move)
        {
            Thread thMove = new Thread(unused => PasteFromMove(item.ToolTipText, collection));
            thMove.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            Thread thCopy = new Thread(unused => PasteFromCopy(item.ToolTipText, collection));
            thCopy.Start();
        }

    }

    private void listView1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyState & 8) == 8)
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        else
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }

    private void listView1_ItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.DoDragDrop(e.Item,DragDropEffects.All);
    }
```